# Getting label with colon for model's field in a form

Tags: yii2

I need to have `Body:` (with colon at the end), not `Body` rendered as label for each field in my form. How can I achieve this the best way?

I tried modifying `fieldConfig => template` in `ActiveForm::begin` by adding `div class=\"\">{label}:</div>` into it:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'edit-form',
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
    'fieldConfig' => [
    'template' => "<div class=\"\">{label}:</div>\n<div class=\"\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"\">{error}</div>",
    'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'edit-label'],
]]); ?>
```

but it is wrong. Colon is rendered as separate DOM element, with incorrect styling and looks ugly.

I tried doing this awfully in CSS:

```
.edit-label::after { 
    content: ":";
}
```

but this is even worse.

I remember, that I made a lot of stupid things in Yii1 to get this. I don't want to repeat these stupid things, when implementing this in Yii2. What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

When using Bootstrap 3 ([`yii\bootstrap\ActiveField`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html)) you can use additional placeholders in the `$template` and you need to replace `{label}` with `{beginLabel}{labelTitle}:{endLabel}`:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'edit-form',
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'form-horizontal',
        'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'
    ],
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => "<div class=\"\">{beginLabel}{labelTitle}:{endLabel}</div>\n<div class=\"\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"\">{error}</div>",
        'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'edit-label'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

I don't know, how to solve this problem, if you're using basic [`yii\widgets\ActiveField`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html) instead.